# "Index was outside the bounds of the array" problem with my sort program

Tags: arrays, vb.net, indexing

I have got a program using the vb.net framework and it seems to be getting an error. Its simply just a BubbleSort algorithm that I have used before yet for some reason it isn't working. To start the program the user places in a txt file that presents itself in a listbox, this part works fine. Entering the next form is where the information from the textbox is sorted using the BubbleSort, after a button click the listbox will clear and paste the new sorted list, into the same listbox. That's when the error appears.

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub btnNameSort_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNameSort.Click

    lstSortArray.Items.Clear()

    Dim Data() As String = DataEntry.lstPatientArray.Items.Cast(Of Object).Select(Function(o) DataEntry.lstPatientArray.GetItemText(o)).ToArray

    Count = DataEntry.lstPatientArray.Items.Count

    Dim Swapped As Boolean
    Dim comparisonNo As Integer
    Dim temp As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Swapped = True

    While Swapped = True
        Swapped = False
        comparisonNo = 1
        While comparisonNo < Count
            If Data(comparisonNo) > Data(comparisonNo + 1) Then
                temp = Data(comparisonNo)
                Data(comparisonNo) = Data(comparisonNo + 1)
                Data(comparisonNo + 1) = temp
                Swapped = True
            End If
            comparisonNo = comparisonNo + 1
        End While
    End While

    For i = 1 To Count
        lstSortArray.Items.Add(Data(Count))
    Next

End Sub
```

The Line at which the error appears:
If Data(comparisonNo) > Data(comparisonNo + 1) Then

DataEntry.lstPatientArray is the listbox on the other form if you need to know, and Count has been declared its just at the start of the form as an integer.

I am new to coding so any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick edit, accidently said, "information from the textbox" where I meant to say information from the listbox.

Comment: Count -1 in your for loop.  But really some simple debugging could of told you that.  Even better use array.length or better still a for each loop which avoids array indexes altogether

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in .net are zero based. The index of the first element of the array is 0. When an array is initialized in code, as you have done here, the index of the last element will be one less than the Count. Remember we started at zero.

We don't need `i` because we are using a `For Each` loop to display the result.

Inside the first loop, you don't want to set `comparisonNo = 1`. The array indexes start at zero. To keep the indexes in range we need to subtract 2 from `Length`. The indexes end one less than the `Length` and when we compare to i +1 we need to subtract another 1.

```
**EDIT**

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim a() = {"Monty Reyes", "Kier Burke", "Kallum Wiley", "Raja Krueger", "Clarissa Webb", "Connah Mathews", "Alisa Bassett", "Emmeline Mills"}
    Dim Swapvalue As String
    For ii = 0 To a.Length - 2
        For i = 0 To a.Length - 2
            If a(i) > a(i + 1) Then
                Swapvalue = a(i)
                a(i) = a(i + 1)
                a(i + 1) = Swapvalue
            End If
        Next
    Next

    For Each st In a
        Debug.Print(st)
    Next
End Sub
```

Of course you can always do...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim a() = {"Monty Reyes", "Kier Burke", "Kallum Wiley", "Raja Krueger", "Clarissa Webb", "Connah Mathews", "Alisa Bassett", "Emmeline Mills"}
    Array.Sort(a)
    For Each st In a
        Debug.Print(st)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey just a problem with the while loop, it goes through but it seems to only do it once, say for the names I have in my Data() is:
Monty Reyes, Kier Burke, Kallum Wiley, Raja Krueger, Clarissa Webb, Connah Mathews, Alisa Bassett, Emmeline Mills
This turns into: Kier Burke, Kallum Wiley, Monty Reyes, Clarissa Webb, Connah Mathews, Alisa Bassett, Emmeline Mills, Raja Krueger. It doesn't sort the whole list.

Comment: See new code below EDIT. This is called a bubble sort. I must have been taking a nap before.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help, it worked perfectly! Sorry for taking time out of your day for you to help me with this.

Comment: I am glad it is working. The best was to thank someone on Stack Overflow is to accept their answer. You can do that by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. This helps you with a few points and me with 15 points and future readers finding accepted answers.